# How to compress iPhone QuickTime screen recording's file size?

Tags: iphone, quicktime, encoding, compression, video-capture

I've recorded my iPhone screen through QuickTime on my MacBook and made several recordings already. Unfortunately, the resulting files are too large. They get saved in .MOV format, and 10 mins takes up about 600-700 MB.

How can I compress these iPhone 7 screen recordings made through QuickTime so that the file sizes become smaller?

Comment: I'd recompress them with Handbrake. (Note I didn't put this as an answer because it's a separate step, though it will make the resulting files smaller).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to compress the video without losing much quality use HandBrake with these settings:

- Choose .mp4
- Tick the Web optimized box
- Quality, constant quality: 25
- Framerate: same as source, variable framerate.
- x264 preset: Slow

(- Btw use x264 instead of x265 if you want to be able to watch the video on most devices)

Answer (score 1):

You could compress it further using **iMovie** (which comes preinstalled with new Macs starting in October 2013).

1. Create a new **Movie Project**.
2. Drag your *.mov* movie into the bottom panel.
3. Click **File** → **Share** → **File…**
4. Adjust **Resolution** and **Quality** to your liking. iMovie will give you an estimated file size on-the-fly).